# Taking away a column in TSQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

```
SELECT VendorName, COUNT(*) as Total_Invoices
FROM   Invoices JOIN Vendors ON Invoices.VendorID = Vendors.VendorID
WHERE  Vendors.VendorName = 'IBM'
GROUP BY VendorName
ORDER BY Total_Invoices DESC
```

It will bring up

```
VendorName  Total_Invoices
IBM                2
```

I want to make it so it just says

```
Total_Invoices
     2
```

without the IBM VendorName being shown but still counting the Total Invoices from IBM

Comment: Did you try running the query without the `VendorName`?

Answer (score 4):

you can safely remove `VendorName` on this case.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as Total_Invoices
FROM   Invoices JOIN Vendors ON Invoices.VendorID = Vendors.VendorID
WHERE  Vendors.VendorName = 'IBM'
GROUP BY VendorName
ORDER BY Total_Invoices DESC
```

`select`, on the other hand, is also called *projection*. you can safely remove it without taking any harm. but removing it on the `GROUP BY` clause is a very different thing already.

Comment: + 1, you were the fastest :)

Comment: In this case I would also remove the `GROUP BY`

Comment: @Lamak no, it would be very different thing, the two will yield different results.

Comment: @JohnWoo The `WHERE` clause will only return `IBM` so you don't need a `GROUP BY` demo with both versions -- http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/91db4/1

Comment: @bluefeet thanks for that, because I was thinking about this http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b436b/1

Answer (score 3):

You just have to clear the `VendorName` from the `Select`. 
And you don't need to use `GROUP BY` or `ORDER BY` in this case

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as Total_Invoices
FROM   Invoices JOIN Vendors ON Invoices.VendorID = Vendors.VendorID
WHERE  Vendors.VendorName = 'IBM'
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove VendorName from SELECT.